# Получить доступ к файлу, в который постоянно записываются данные

Tags: c#, файлы, ftp

Привет) Возникла проблема:
Необходимо каждые N минут (при событии OnTimerTick) отправлять лог файл (.txt) на FTP сервер. Проблема в том, что файл, который мне необходимо отправить постоянно дополняется записями о состоянии системы, каждую секунду.

Что я пробовал:

Отправить любой другой файл. Все работает и отправляется, используется вот такая конструкция:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");  
    client.UploadFile("ftp://url/folder/filename.txt", "filename.txt");
}
```

Просто записывать логи в файл. Здесь тоже все в порядке, все работает.

Указать FileShare.ReadWrite при дополнении файла

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("filename.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    sw.WriteLine("info");
    sw.Close();
}
```

Тоже не помогло, на FTP ничего не отправляется.

Пробовал создавать копию лог файла и отправлять копию

```
File.Copy("filename.txt", "copy.txt");
SendToFTP(); // отправляет файл на FTP (с другими файлами все работает)
```

При отправке копии она все же отправляется, но файл пуст.

Как я могу получить доступ к этому файлу и отправить его?

Comment: А дополняет файл эта же программа или сторонняя?

Comment: эта же программа, все делает один .exe

Comment: Ну так отправляйте в том же таймере, что и добавляет записи, чтобы эти две задачи не выполнялись параллельно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP вызываю метод SendToFTP() каждый раз, когда записывается новая строка в лог. (в том же таймере) На FTP фал действительно отправляется, но лишь с первым логом с момента старта программы. Разбираться буду :/